# Basic jQuery with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I was trying to use jQuery in Rails. I'm having a problem getting started off. I need to attach a jQuery function. Suppose, I have this link_to helper 
`<%= link_to "Sign in", :id => "user_sign_in" %>`

I need to show a popup window when a user clicks this link. What do I write in my application.js file? This is what I have so far, but it's not working:

`jQuery(function(){
    $("#user_sign_in").live("click", function(){
        alert('I'm hit')
    })
};)`


Please suggest!

Comment: Read this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208412/rails-3-how-to-use-the-link-to-helper-to-open-a-popup

Comment: This is plain Javascript, my purpose is to learn to use jQuery with Rails. Thanks.

Comment: do you download rails.js for jquery?  https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails link at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Augusto has said, firstly you need to escape the single quote in I'm, unless you change to the double quotes wrapping that string.

Secondly, the semi-colon at the end of that example should go **after** the last parenthesis.

This all assumes you even have jQuery installed, which you can double-check by looking at **public/javascripts** directory and verifying that jquery.js is present, as well as making sure that your application layout in **views/layouts** directory includes it.

If this answer has helped you solve the problem, accept it which will improve your accept rate. Cheers