# Ruby on Rails - cannot open a second application as a popup window using Java script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I took a look at various posts like this [How to use the link_to helper to open a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208412/how-to-use-the-link-to-helper-to-open-a-popup/8828841#8828841)
but I wasn't able to make it work.

Here is my code:

in the `application.js` I included this code:

```
$('a[data-popup]').live('click', function(e) {
  window.open( $(this).attr('href'), "Popup", "height=600, width=600" );
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

in the `assessment_controller.rb` I included this method:

```
  def open_second_app
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

in the assessments index page `index.html.erb` I included the link:

```
<div>
  <%= button_to 'New', new_assessment_path, method: :get %>
  <%= button_to 'Home', root_path, method: :get %>
  <%= link_to( 'Open Second Application', open_second_app_path, 'data-popup' => true ) %>
</div>
```

I also have a `open_second_app.js.erb` file containing this single line:

```
window.open (<%= open_second_app_path %>, "Second Appllication Window", "width=600,height=600");
```

When I click the link, I am getting this error:

```
Showing /Users/liviu-mac/ror/levi-test-01/app/views/assessments/index.html.erb where line #34 raised:
undefined local variable or method `open_second_app_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe3c6fa4040>:0x007fe3c40ae4c0>
```

The main application is running as `localhost:3000`.
The second application is running as `localhost:3001`.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open in a new window you need to set the target to blank. See this post: [How to use "_blank" or "_new" in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290335/how-to-use-blank-or-new-in-rails)

Updating to account for the question you made in a comment. To use a different url in production than in development:

```
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
  <% second_app_url = 'http://whatever' %>
<% else %>
  <% second_app_url = 'http://localhost:whatever' %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously better to handle this in a method than in your views but just showing you the condition for example purposes.

Comment: I changed the line in the index page (as indicated) as this:
`  <%= link_to( 'Open Second Application', 'http://0.0.0.0:3001', 'data-popup' => true, target: '_blank' ) %>`
and is working. I am starting the main app with the command `rails s` and the second app wth command `rails s -p 3001 -b 0.0.0.0`. 
Is there anything I need to change when deploying with `heroku` ?

Comment: Just the production url.

Comment: But if am replacing 0.0.0.0 with my-second-app.herokuapp.com the development for first app will use the same heroku deployed second app instead of the development instance.

Comment: just add a condition for using the different urls in development. I'll update my answer to show you how.